# How to build a BLE Test interface running on windows, Linux PC with BLE dongle

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am starting to develop BLE peripheral devices (with own GATT profiles etc.).

I am looking for test equipment to test those devices. Is it possible to use a BLE/Bluetooth USB Dongle, which can interact with a test application to run on a normal Linux or windows PC?

When I say "test" I do not mean radio tests routines.

**So i am looking for existing solutions/tools/frameworks for this purpose.**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of great tools for Linux that can be used for BLE development and testing.  These include:

- bluetoothctl
- l2ping
- hcitool
- gatttool

However my go to choice for testing is an Android application available on the Android App Store called "nRF Connect".

I have not found comparable tools for the Windows platform.

Comment: i will check and try the nordic App  "nrfConnect"  for android.  thx

Comment: nrfConnect works fine for a first try.   to interface a nordic dev. kit from PC i found this driver:   [pc-ple-driver](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/pc-ble-driver) .   sound nice, i have not try it.